# zero errors trying to connect user to local mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, unix, ssh, localhost

using npm **[any-db](https://www.npmjs.org/package/any-db)** and **[any-db-mysql](https://www.npmjs.org/package/any-db-mysql)**

```
var db = anyDB.createConnection('mysql://db_user:921F9DB7pnn0ka777@localhost/db1',function(e,r){if(e){console.log('db.err: '+e);}}); // also tried 127.0.0.1
```

I should see the console log

```
db.err: null
```

But I don't. (I see no error at all).

```
db.query("SELECT * FROM btns WHERE id='1'").on('row',function(e,r){
    console.log('err: '+e);
    console.dir(r);
    });
```

The above also prints nothing (not even an error);

In my ssh session mysql> show databases;

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| db1                |
| test               |
+--------------------+
```

mysql> use db1;

mysql> show tables;

```
+---------------------------+
| Tables_in_db1             |
+---------------------------+
| btns                      |
+---------------------------+
```

The db_user is in database 'mysql', setup like so:

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD('921F9DB7pnn0ka777') where user='db_user';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> exit;
```

Comment: Use something like  ```var db = anyDB.createConnection('mysql://db_user:921F9DB7pnn0ka777@localhost/db1',function(e,r){if(e){console.log('db.err: '+e);} else {console.log('Connected',e);} });``` to output something if there's no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you expect the first case to ever output anything? You're only logging if the error argument is a truthy value (which `null` is not).

For the the second case, `any-db`/`any-db-mysql` does not emit 'row' events for the streaming (non-callback) version. The streaming version returns a readable stream, so you need to use standard methods for getting data from a readable stream (in object mode):

- Listen for 'data' events where the 'data' event handler's argument is a row object.
- OR call `.read()` repeatedly to get row objects

Also for the streaming version, you can listen for an 'error' event to check for errors.

Comment: Because it normally outputs exactly what I said. Normally I connect to another host using cPanel, the difference now is that it is local host and no admin panel at all only pure ssh and I have made the dumb mistake of expecting the newer version of any-db to be like the old 0.0.4 version I am so fond of! If anyone wants the old version that **does** output row events you also need to add node-mysql@2.1.1 inside any-db/node_modules. +1 btw